# Date stuck as unformattable in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to plot time series data and my date column is stuck like this, and I cannot seem to figure out what datatype it is to change it, as adding `verbose = True` doesn't yield any explanation for the data.

Here is a screenshot of the output [Date formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1dS9.png)

Here is the code I have for importing the dataset and all the formatting I've done to it. Ultimately, I want date and time to be separate values, but I cannot figure out why it's auto formatting it and applying today's date.

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

df['Avg_value'] = (df['Open'] + df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close'])/4

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Any help would be appreciated

The output I'd be looking for would be something like:

```
Date: 2016-01-04 10:00:00
```

As one column rather than 2 separate ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a Pandas Series into `pd.to_datetime(...)`, it parses the values and returns a new Series of dtype `datetime64[ns]` containing the parsed values:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["12:30:00"]))
0   2021-08-24 12:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The reason you see today's date is that a `datetime64` value must have **both date and time information**. Since the date is missing, the current date is substituted by default.

Pandas does not really have a dtype that supports "just time of day, no date" (there is one that supports time intervals, such as "5 minutes"). The Python standard library does, however: the [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) class.

Pandas provides a convenience function called the [`.dt accessor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) for extracting a Series of `datetime.time` objects from a Series of `datetime64` objects:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["12:30:00"])).dt.time
0    12:30:00
dtype: object
```

Note that the dtype is just `object` which is the fallback dtype Pandas uses for anything which is not natively supported by Pandas or NumPy. This means that working with these `datetime.time` objects will be a bit slower than working with a native Pandas dtype, but this probably won't be a bottleneck for your application.

Recommended reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html